# How can i open an interactive bash shell from nodejs REPL console

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, pipe, sh

I want to open a bash shell from nodejs console.

I have tried everything from child_process module, but i did not managed to find a solution where i can see $ prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the child inherit the `stdio`, here you have a working example (Linux) :

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const shell = spawn('sh',[], { stdio: 'inherit' })
shell.on('close',(code)=>{console.log('[shell] terminated :',code)})
```

example output :

```
sh-4.4$ uname
Linux
sh-4.4$ exit
exit
[shell] terminated : 0
```

---

Remember to replace `sh` with the correct *shell* for your platform requirements